# Imported svg converted to mesh shows original svg in render

Tags: rendering, svg

I have imported two .svg files and converted them to meshes; have then animated these meshes.

On rendering the original .svg files also appear, but without animation as shown here:

[image]

The white circle is the original .svg for the yellow coin-shaped object amd the marbled mask for the red mask object. Both objects have been rotated by about 75 degrees here, but the two original .svg's are visible in their original poisitions.

How do I correct this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: No, @Crantisz, my problem is things showing up that shouldn't show up. I've tried different render engines, but they all show the unwanted image

Comment: @Dzseti Also there is no need to use svg while you can do all your drawings directly in blender better than any software :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Outliner's view layer try to turn off the camera icon [image]

If it doesn't existed (which is by default) enable it in filter menu :
[image]